# Calculating Business Hours Between 2 x date time fields in Crystal Reports

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a requirement to calculate the time taken within business hours (08:00 - 18:00 Mon - Fri) between a start date/time and end date/time (recorded as a datetime field in MS SQL database), as a formula within a Crystal Report.

I have searched for a solution and am working to the following formulas provided on Ken Hamady website (http://www.kenhamady.com/formulas/form13.shtml, http://www.kenhamady.com/formulas/form01.shtml)

Business Days Formula:

```
WhileReadingRecords;
Local DateVar Start := date({Events.CreatedDateTime});
Local DateVar End := date({Events.CompletedDateTime});  
Local NumberVar Weeks;
Local NumberVar Days;
Local Numbervar Hol;
DateVar Array Holidays;

Weeks:= (Truncate (End - dayofWeek(End) + 1
- (Start - dayofWeek(Start) + 1)) /7 ) * 5;
Days := DayOfWeek(End) - DayOfWeek(Start) + 1 +
(if DayOfWeek(Start) = 1 then -1 else 0)  +
(if DayOfWeek(End) = 7 then -1 else 0);   

Local NumberVar i;
For i := 1 to Count (Holidays)
do (if DayOfWeek ( Holidays[i] ) in 2 to 6 and
     Holidays[i] in start to end then Hol:=Hol+1 );

Weeks + Days - Hol
```

Turnaround Time Formula:

```
WhileReadingRecords;

NumberVar Days := {@Business Days Formula};  
TimeVar SetStart := TimeValue( "8:00");  
TimeVar SetEnd   := TimeValue("18:00");    
TimeVar StartTime := TimeValue({Events.CreatedDateTime});
TimeVar EndTime   := TimeValue({Events.CompletedDateTime}); 


Days * ((SetEnd - SetStart) / 3600)
-  ((SetEnd     - EndTime)  / 3600)
-  ((StartTime - SetStart)  / 3600)
```

I am getting unexpected results where the start and end times are outside of business hours (as the author warned).

My objective, is to then create formulas for the start and end date, so if they fall outside of business hours, they default to the next working day @ 08:00. These formulas can then be referenced in the code instead of the date/times from the database.

e.g if the field is 08/12/2017 18:06:00 it should be converted to 11/12/2017 08:00:00. (taking into account weekends)

Ideally this should also take into account the list of holidays detailed in the "Holiday List" formula:

```
BeforeReadingRecords;
DateVar Array Holidays := [
Date (2017,12,25)
];
0
```

Can you advise?

Comment: can you post full formula?

Comment: Edited post to include formulas